# My Contact form submit button not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying send email from contact form by fetching data from another page ( Home Page - Index.php). But my contact didn't perform action which redirect the another page.

When I click On submit Button It didn't work.

```html
<form method="post" id="form" class="contact-form" action="/contact.php">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="search">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
                                    <span class="alert-error"></span>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" type="email" required>
                                    <span class="alert-error"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact" minlength="10" maxlength="10" placeholder="Contact Number*" type="text" required>
                                    <span class="alert-error"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="contact" name="subject" placeholder="Subject*" type="text" required>
                                    <span class="alert-error"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group comments">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="message" placeholder="Tell Us About Your Project *" required></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
                                    Send Message <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Alert Message -->
                            <!-- <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div id="message" class="alert-msg"></div>
                            </div> -->
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to the thunder dome! At first glance everything you need to expect properly working code seems to be intact. So my question is if you have created the contact.php file? Or in what way exactly is it not working? Like it's navigating but you get a missing page error? Or when you click it nothing happens at all?

Comment: Hi! :) In addition to @Kenpachi's comment, it might be helpful for people trying to answer your question if they can see the bug in action, since the code you posted looks OK. Are you able to provide us with a page that reproduces the bug for us to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Most Probably you have error in contact.php. try to switch on error_reporting, just add these lines at the top of contact.php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```